# Path, /usr/bin/ and /usr/local/bin/

Tags: linux, macos, bash, command-line, watchr

I installed *watchr* on OS X (10.8.3) using `gem install watchr`. And it's installed in */usr/bin/watchr*

```
$ which watchr
/usr/bin/watchr
```

However, when I tried to call it `$ watchr -v`, the system couldn't find it.

```
$ watchr -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/watchr: No such file or directory
```

I think this is related to how the path is set up on my machine. My questions:

1. What is the right way to fix it?
2. In general, what programs should go to `/usr/bin/` vs. `/usr/local/bin/`?
3. When I do e.g. `$ /usr/bin/watchr -e 'watch(./hello.txt) ...'`, are we looking at the *hello.txt* in the current directory or in */usr/bin/* i.e. the same directory as *watchr*?

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu) closing and reopening the terminal fixed the issue.

Answer (score 11):

The path to your command was cached with a bad value.  Try to update the cached directory that bash has stored for the path.

```
hash -d watchr
```

I found the answer over here [which ctags shows /usr/local/bin/ctags but when I run ctags it runs /usr/bin/ctags. How is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225705/which-ctags-shows-usr-local-bin-ctags-but-when-i-run-ctags-it-runs-usr-bin-cta)

Comment: Thanks, man. I just ran into this when setting up Erlang and Elixir. Their official repository messed up in Ubuntu / Linux Mint. Your comment saved me from a possibly long bug-hunt and may do so in the future too. ;) I can't believe I didn't know that one before. (Any more keywords for future googlers I should add to my answer?)

Answer (score 2):

Is /usr/local/bin/watchr a broken symlink? That would make `which watchr` not include it but `watchr` would print this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/watchr: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why the `gem` that comes with OS X installs programs in /usr/bin/, but generally /usr/bin/ is meant for preinstalled programs, and package managers use something like /opt/local/bin/ or /usr/local/bin/.

I also have /usr/local/bin/ before other folders on the path, and I put most programs that I install or compile manually to /usr/local/bin/. I used to have a separate ~/bin/ folder, but it's easy to find non-Homebrew programs with something like `find /usr/local/bin ! -lname '../Cellar/*'`.

Related questions about /usr/local/bin/ in general:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/what-is-usr-local-bin-came-across-it-in-an-script-installation-for-applescript

Comment: I saw several symlinks in _/usr/local/bin/_ but didn't find a symlink for _watchr_. Were you saying that _/usr/bin/_ is more for the system install; whereas _/usr/local/bin/_ is for a manual install i.e. programs that were installed manually by a user manually?

Comment: After experimenting more on this, here's what I learned. As explained above {{/usr/local/bin/}} is used often by package manager e.g. _brew_  installs {{/usr/local/Cellar/*}}. For manual install, it's really up to the user where to place the bits.

Answer (score 1):

create a file called .profile in your home directory and add the following line.

```
export PATH=“/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:$PATH”
```